# Can't log in to any desktop environment other than GNOME on Raspberry Pi 5

Tags: login, raspberrypi, mate

Raspberry Pi Imager only lets you install regular Ubuntu instead of Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, etc. Figuring that I could just change the desktop environment on the Pi itself I installed Ubuntu desktop. The only thing I did on this installation of Ubuntu is connect to Wi-Fi, update all the preinstalled software, install the ubuntu-mate-desktop package, log out, then select MATE on the gear icon on the bottom right of the login screen. Entering the password just restarts the login screen as if nothing happened, however it will let me log back in to GNOME if I check the Ubuntu option instead. Whatever the problem it is with the default settings for the Ubuntu installation that Raspberry Pi Imager gives you.

I don't think the problem is with MATE itself because to check, I installed a bunch of other desktop environments, and "Ubuntu" is still literally the only option on this list that works. Every other one just restarts the login screen in the exact same way

[image]

Comment: You've not provided what to me is the basic starting point, what Ubuntu product & release of that product you're asking about.  A default Desktop install only includes the GNOME Desktop (*which can have a few login options*) and other desktops require manual install. Not all *flavors* offer raspberry pi images (*but are available on R.Pi's via package install*)

Comment: Ubuntu Desktop 23.10 64-bit, the only one provided for the Pi 5



"(but are available on R.Pi's via package install)" yes that's exactly what I did as per the post